# Can't see tag "<>" braces due to highlight color same as braces in Windows terminal

Tags: colorscheme, highlight, color

I'm new to Vim and am having an issue with highlight color of matching braces in Vim.
if I type: `<html>` and my cursor is at the one of the <> greater/less-than brace then I can't see the brace because the color of <> braces is same  as the highlight i.e light blue.

here is an image:

[image: screenshot with evening colorscheme]

Ok so I tried a different `colorscheme` and found that in slate the color of the braces and the bars are different so I can see them but in other schemes this problem exists.
here is the image in slate colorscheme:

[image: screenshot with slate colorscheme]

**How to change the highlight color or syntax highlighting color?**

Comment: would you need to change your cursor or the html tags?

Comment: @padawin my cursor is alright as long as i'm not on the `<>` braces. But when I am, it shows/highlights the matched braces and they are not visible anymore. I see 2 light-blue bars instead.

Answer (score 2):

The highlight of the matching brace is ruled by the `MatchParen` group.

You can customize it with the `highlight` command.

Here's an example:

```
highlight MatchParen guifg=Black guibg=Yellow
```